# Python PyObjC_IdToPython(@protocol(NSURLSessionStreamDelegate)) error

Tags: python, protocols, pyobjc

when i try to install pyobjc-framework-Cocoa i see this error:

```
In file included from Modules/_Foundation.m:15:
    Modules/_Foundation_protocols.m:14:28: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSProgressReporting'
        p = PyObjC_IdToPython(@protocol(NSProgressReporting)); Py_XDECREF(p);
                           ^
    Modules/_Foundation_protocols.m:15:28: error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSURLSessionStreamDelegate'
        p = PyObjC_IdToPython(@protocol(NSURLSessionStreamDelegate)); Py_XDECREF(p);
                           ^
    2 errors generated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 4):

I was able to avoid the problem in the following environment:

```
Mac OS X 10.10.5  
pip8.1.2  
python3.4
```

Please try the following command.

> pip uninstall pyobjc-core
>   pip install pyobjc==3.0.4

The cause of the problem seems to be a delivery mistake of "pyobjc-core3.1.1".
It should go well if unified in 3.0.4.

cheers!

Comment: make sure to have no spaces in "pyobjc==3.0.4"